# Clickhouse async insert settings implementation

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-go

How to correctly using async insert settings in clickhouse?

I am following the documentation on clickhouse website here: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/optimize/asynchronous-inserts to use async inserts.

I wanted to apply async insert settings at user level. I used approach mentioned here https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/optimize/asynchronous-inserts#enabling-asynchronous-inserts , verified that async insert is enabled from system.settings table in clickhouse.

Now when I insert into tables using this user logged in on the server, doing it via console only using `INSERT INTO table() values ()` command. It inserts the record into table but this insertion log doesn't appear in `asynchronous_insert_log` table.

When can this happen? What all logs I can use to debug this.

Update:
When I do INSERT INTO Table SETTINGS `async_insert=1 wait_for_async_insert=1` values (), then it actually shows up in asynchronous_insert_log table else not.

Comment: Not sure why the records would be deleted. You might have to share your table DDL

Comment: Got the issue for the deleted rows, it was my mistake, I had a ttl attached on the table rows on a datetime field for 3 months, and I was not passing it when testing async inserts, so it took default value of 1970-01-01 and when clickhouse's merge process ran, it deleted that row.

Answer (score 2):

This enables async inserts at the user level:

```
ALTER USER default SETTINGS async_insert = 1
```

But that doesn't enable the logging. You have to configure the `asynchronous_insert_log` by adding something like the following in a new file in `config.d`:

```
<clickhouse>
    <asynchronous_insert_log>
        <database>system</database>
        <table>asynchronous_insert_log</table>
        <flush_interval_milliseconds>7500</flush_interval_milliseconds>
        <max_size_rows>1048576</max_size_rows>
        <reserved_size_rows>8192</reserved_size_rows>
        <buffer_size_rows_flush_threshold>524288</buffer_size_rows_flush_threshold>
        <flush_on_crash>false</flush_on_crash>
        <engine>Engine = MergeTree PARTITION BY event_date ORDER BY event_time TTL event_date + INTERVAL 30 day</engine>
    </asynchronous_insert_log>
</clickhouse>
```

More details in the docs: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings#server_configuration_parameters-asynchronous_insert_log

Comment: This configuration is already there in my config.xml file

Comment: So are you seeing entries in this log table now?

Comment: When I do `INSERT INTO Table SETTINGS async_insert=1 wait_for_async_insert=1 values ()`, then it actually shows up in asynchronous_insert_log table else when I am doing `insert into table () values ()`, it doesn't show up in asynchronous_insert_log table.

Comment: So it's a setting issue - not an async_insert issue. For whatever reason, your `async_insert=1` is not getting applied. Make sure you're sending the query as the `default` user (since that is who you applied the setting to) or send the setting with each insert using the `SETTINGS` clause